solve androidmanifest.xml fill in flutter
D:\flutter project\gn_demo\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.example.gn_demo.MainActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android:exported when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.


Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
solve this erron in flutter
for androidmanifest.xml fill
